How to turn a read only excel file to Read/write using VB within CMM mananger
I'm trying to make a read-only Excel file from the engineering department automatically convert to a read/write after or before I've re-named and saved the new file.
"Blankfile" is the read only file. This program is for inspecting parts. The first part, or aperture, opens the Excel file from blankfile, then renames it properly and then asks the user to input other data like your name, date, etc. The parts after the first, open the newly named file.
All of this code works besides the attributes part.Firstly I tried:
filename.Attributes = 0

but I was quickly corrected this is because filename its a string. How do I change the attibutes of this file then? Do I define it as an object before its a string?? My boss told me he just used the above code, but this is obviously incorrect. I've also tried
Set FSO = filename.Attributes = 0

' Open Excel file for inspection results

aperture = InputBox("Please enter the number aperture you are inspecting 1 to 30 (NOT the apertures item#)", "Current Aperture")

ponumber = InputBox("Please enter the PO number", "PO number")

'BOTH must be xlsx files, it will not open or use xls files
blankfile = "C:\pdm_vault\released\cad\510657 aperture, type-a tube anti-ghost, id=2.6\510657RD_IRXXXXX.xls"



If aperture = 1 OR aperture = 2 OR aperture = 3 OR aperture = 4 OR aperture = 5 OR aperture = 6 Then

filename = "Z:\RIT Resources\Materials Management\Receiving Inspection\Receiving Inspection Reports\Apertures\510657\510657RD_IR" & ponumber & ".xlsx"


If aperture = 2 OR aperture = 3 OR aperture = 4 OR aperture = 5 OR aperture = 6 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ElseIf aperture = 1 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call FSO.CopyFile(blankfile, filename)

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

filename.Attributes = 0

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")


qtyrecieved = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of received apertures:", "Quanity Recieved")

qtyinspected = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of inspected apertures. (Leave blank if the specific inspection file fills this out already):", "Quanity Inspected")

incomingdate = InputBox("Please enter the date these apertures came in:", "Incoming Date")

vendor = InputBox("Please enter the name of the vendor:", "Vendor")

yourname = InputBox("Please enter your name:", "Name")

todaysdate = InputBox("Please enter todays date:", "Todays Date")

' Record quanity recieved number
xlsWS.cells(5, 12).Value = qtyrecieved

'Record quanity inspected amount, skip if it is blank
If qtyinspected > 0 Then
xlsWS.cells(6, 12).Value = qtyinspected
End If

'Record date that parts came in
xlsWS.cells(2, 8).Value = incomingdate

'Record the name of vendor
xlsWS.cells(3, 8).Value = vendor

'Record the PO number
xlsWS.cells(4, 8).Value = ponumber

'Record yourname
xlsWS.cells(17, 3).Value = yourname

'Record todaysdate
xlsWS.cells(17, 7).Value = todaysdate

End If
End If


If aperture = 7 OR aperture = 8 OR aperture = 9 OR aperture = 10 OR aperture = 11 OR aperture = 12 Then
filename = "Z:\RIT Resources\Materials Management\Receiving Inspection\Receiving Inspection Reports\Apertures\510657\510657RD_IR" & ponumber & "_2.xlsx"

If aperture = 8 OR aperture = 9 OR aperture = 10 OR aperture = 11 OR aperture = 12 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ElseIf aperture = 7 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call FSO.CopyFile(blankfile, filename)

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

qtyrecieved = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of received apertures:", "Quanity Recieved")

qtyinspected = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of inspected apertures. (Leave blank if the specific inspection file fills this out already):", "Quanity Inspected")

incomingdate = InputBox("Please enter the date these apertures came in:", "Incoming Date")

vendor = InputBox("Please enter the name of the vendor:", "Vendor")

yourname = InputBox("Please enter your name:", "Name")

todaysdate = InputBox("Please enter todays date:", "Todays Date")

' Record quanity recieved number
xlsWS.cells(5, 12).Value = qtyrecieved

'Record quanity inspected amount, skip if it is blank
If qtyinspected > 0 Then
xlsWS.cells(6, 12).Value = qtyinspected
End If

'Record date that parts came in
xlsWS.cells(2, 8).Value = incomingdate

'Record the name of vendor
xlsWS.cells(3, 8).Value = vendor

'Record the PO number
xlsWS.cells(4, 8).Value = ponumber

'Record yourname
xlsWS.cells(34, 3).Value = yourname

'Record todaysdate
xlsWS.cells(34, 7).Value = todaysdate

End If
End If


If aperture = 13 OR aperture = 14 OR aperture = 15 OR aperture = 16 OR aperture = 17 OR aperture = 18 Then

filename = "Z:\RIT Resources\Materials Management\Receiving Inspection\Receiving Inspection Reports\Apertures\510657\510657RD_IR" & ponumber & "_3.xlsx"

If aperture = 14 OR aperture = 15 OR aperture = 16 OR aperture = 17 OR aperture = 18 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")


ElseIf aperture = 13 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call FSO.CopyFile(blankfile, filename)

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

qtyrecieved = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of received apertures:", "Quanity Recieved")

qtyinspected = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of inspected apertures. (Leave blank if the specific inspection file fills this out already):", "Quanity Inspected")

incomingdate = InputBox("Please enter the date these apertures came in:", "Incoming Date")

vendor = InputBox("Please enter the name of the vendor:", "Vendor")

yourname = InputBox("Please enter your name:", "Name")

todaysdate = InputBox("Please enter todays date:", "Todays Date")

' Record quanity recieved number
xlsWS.cells(5, 12).Value = qtyrecieved

'Record quanity inspected amount, skip if it is blank
If qtyinspected > 0 Then
xlsWS.cells(6, 12).Value = qtyinspected
End If

'Record date that parts came in
xlsWS.cells(2, 8).Value = incomingdate

'Record the name of vendor
xlsWS.cells(3, 8).Value = vendor

'Record the PO number
xlsWS.cells(4, 8).Value = ponumber

'Record yourname
xlsWS.cells(34, 3).Value = yourname

'Record todaysdate
xlsWS.cells(34, 7).Value = todaysdate

End If
End If






If aperture = 19 OR aperture = 20 OR aperture = 21 OR aperture = 22 OR aperture = 23 OR aperture = 24 Then

filename = "Z:\RIT Resources\Materials Management\Receiving Inspection\Receiving Inspection Reports\Apertures\510657\510657RD_IR" & ponumber & "_4.xlsx"



If aperture = 20 OR aperture = 21 OR aperture = 22 OR aperture = 23 OR aperture = 24 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ElseIf aperture = 19 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call FSO.CopyFile(blankfile, filename)

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

qtyrecieved = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of received apertures:", "Quanity Recieved")

qtyinspected = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of inspected apertures. (Leave blank if the specific inspection file fills this out already):", "Quanity Inspected")

incomingdate = InputBox("Please enter the date these apertures came in:", "Incoming Date")

vendor = InputBox("Please enter the name of the vendor:", "Vendor")

yourname = InputBox("Please enter your name:", "Name")

todaysdate = InputBox("Please enter todays date:", "Todays Date")

' Record quanity recieved number
xlsWS.cells(5, 12).Value = qtyrecieved

'Record quanity inspected amount, skip if it is blank
If qtyinspected > 0 Then
xlsWS.cells(6, 12).Value = qtyinspected
End If

'Record date that parts came in
xlsWS.cells(2, 8).Value = incomingdate

'Record the name of vendor
xlsWS.cells(3, 8).Value = vendor

'Record the PO number
xlsWS.cells(4, 8).Value = ponumber

'Record yourname
xlsWS.cells(34, 3).Value = yourname

'Record todaysdate
xlsWS.cells(34, 7).Value = todaysdate

End If
End If









If aperture = 25 OR aperture = 26 OR aperture = 27 OR aperture = 28 OR aperture = 29 OR aperture = 30 Then

filename = "Z:\RIT Resources\Materials Management\Receiving Inspection\Receiving Inspection Reports\Apertures\510657\510657RD_IR" & ponumber & "_5.xlsx"




If aperture = 26 OR aperture = 27 OR aperture = 28 OR aperture = 29 OR aperture = 30 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

End If

If aperture = 25 Then

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call FSO.CopyFile(blankfile, filename)

Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Set xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set xlsWS = xlsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

qtyrecieved = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of received apertures:", "Quanity Recieved")

qtyinspected = InputBox("Please enter the total quanity of inspected apertures. (Leave blank if the specific inspection file fills this out already):", "Quanity Inspected")

incomingdate = InputBox("Please enter the date these apertures came in:", "Incoming Date")

vendor = InputBox("Please enter the name of the vendor:", "Vendor")

yourname = InputBox("Please enter your name:", "Name")

todaysdate = InputBox("Please enter todays date:", "Todays Date")

' Record quanity recieved number
xlsWS.cells(5, 12).Value = qtyrecieved

'Record quanity inspected amount, skip if it is blank
If qtyinspected > 0 Then
xlsWS.cells(6, 12).Value = qtyinspected
End If

'Record date that parts came in
xlsWS.cells(2, 8).Value = incomingdate

'Record the name of vendor
xlsWS.cells(3, 8).Value = vendor

'Record the PO number
xlsWS.cells(4, 8).Value = ponumber

'Record yourname
xlsWS.cells(34, 3).Value = yourname

'Record todaysdate
xlsWS.cells(34, 7).Value = todaysdate

End If 
End If


